# How to remove primary key from a mysql table which is primary key and foreign key in the same table as well.?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship, primary-key-design

I have two different table having 20k entries each and mistakenly I have made summaryId as primary key and foreign key in the same table but now I want to remove the primary key constraint which is auto increament  too. When I try drop primary key syntax it returns me an error :

**#1025 - Error on rename of '.\tg#sql-a38_7f' to '.\tg\rest_web_availability_summary_pm' (errno: 150)**

I tried the below query.

```
ALTER TABLE 'table_name' DROP PRIMARY KEY
```

If anybody has any idea please tell me how to remove primary key.

Comment: what command do you use to drop the primary key?

Comment: ALTER TABLE 'table_name' DROP PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, that your field is `auto_increment`. You should remove auto_increment first and then drop the primary key.. so try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL, DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Redefining the column without auto_increment removes it

Comment: I have tried ALTER TABLE 'table_name' DROP PRIMARY KEY
ALTER TABLE 'table_name' DROP PRIMARY KEY 'column_name'
ALTER TABLE 'table_name' DROP PRIMARY KEY 'column_name',ADD PRIMARY KEY(column2);
But none of the above commands did help me.

Comment: @AdeshPandey remove first the `auto_increment` flag from the field. The above statement should work.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, turned out that as it was referenced by other fields, mysql required the column to be unique, so I first added a unique constraint, and lived happily ever after:

```
alter table `mytable` add unique key `key` (`fieldname`);
alter table `mytable` drop primary key; -- which is fieldname...
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you need remove the `FK`s before. On MySQL, do like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` DROP FOREIGN KEY `id_name_fk`;

ALTER TABLE `table_name` DROP INDEX `id_name_fk`;
```